# python version in requirements.txt issues with install requires in setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, setup.py, requirements.txt

I have a requirements.txt file with data like

```
py3DNS==3.1.0; python_version > '3'
scapy-python3==0.23; python_version > '3'
pyDNS==2.3.6; python_version < '3'
scapy==2.4.0; python_version < '3'
```

for specifying python version during installation of libraries

and in setup.py I am using to load requirements from requirements.txt file

```
requirements = open("requirements.txt").read().rsplit()
setup(
install_requires=requirements,
...)
```

and got this

```
requirements = ['py3DNS==3.1.0;', 'python_version', '>', "'3'", 'scapy-python3==0.23;', 'python_version', '>', "'3'", 'pyDNS==2.3.6;', 'python_version', '<', "'3'", 'scapy==2.4.0;', 'python_version', '<', "'3'"]
```

which basically can't be used, I can make changes manually but I wanted to know if there is any generic way to do this stuff

Comment: Hmmm, scapy==2.4.0 works with python3, I dont see the point of having a switch for it

Comment: Why are you processing `requirements.txt` manually in `setup.py`? That's an unusual way to use `requirements.txt`. [The usual way](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files) is `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and it's not clear whether any of the usual reasons to use `requirements.txt` apply here.

Comment: @Cukic0d I am not sure about scapy installation but there is another lib pydns which won't work with python3

Comment: @user2357112 `pip install -r requirements.txt` works with terminal but I want to add data into the setup.py file instead so that user can run `python setup.py install` and be done with it. As a matter of fact I can run the pip command with os.system but I don't  think that will be the best way to do this stuff.

Answer (score -1):

try to split to lines like this:

```
requirements = open("requirements.txt").read().split('\n')
```

which yields

```
requirements = ["py3DNS==3.1.0; python_version > '3'",
"scapy-python3==0.23; python_version > '3'",
"pyDNS==2.3.6; python_version < '3'",
"scapy==2.4.0; python_version < '3'",
'']
```

you can alternativelly do following to get just the package and the version:

```
requirements = list(map(lambda x: x.split(';')[0], requirements)
```

to get

```
['py3DNS==3.1.0', 'scapy-python3==0.23', 'pyDNS==2.3.6', 'scapy==2.4.0', '']
```

Comment: There's a built-in [`splitlines()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines); why not use that?

Comment: I was going to use this method but I wanted to know if python setup.py can work with requirements.txt with different versions, maybe a function that can automatically do the task for me.