# pip-compile for setup.py's install_requires instead of requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, requirements.txt, pip-tools

`pip-compile` enables traceability in pinning requirements inside a `requirements.txt` with an external `requirements.in`.  I really like this

My question is, can we somehow do the same, but for an `install_requires` list inside `setup.py`?

In other words, if I don't have a `requirements.txt` but instead just a `setup.py`, is it possible to use `pip-compile`?

Comment: Generate `requirements.txt` and read it in `setup.py`. You can do simple reaing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50931854/7976758) or you can do more complex [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971236/7976758).

Comment: @phd A best practice question here... would it be better to (a) generate requirements.txt from `install_requires` in setup.py, or (b) parse requirements.txt to generate `install_requires` list in setup.py ?

Comment: @jacaheyo How you gonna automatically generate `requirements.txt` from `install_requires`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, pip-tools supports `pyproject.toml`, `setup.cfg`, and `setup.py` configuration files from version 6.1.0 (2021-04-14).

You should just run:

```bash
pip-compile -o requirements.txt YOUR_CONFIG_FILE
# where YOUR_CONFIG_FILE can be a setup.py
# or even simpler
pip-compile YOUR_CONFIG_FILE
```

Take a look at the documentation:

[Requirements from pyproject.toml](https://pip-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#requirements-from-pyproject-toml)

[Requirements from setup.py and setup.cfg](https://pip-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#requirements-from-setup-py-and-setup-cfg)

[Changelog, verson 6.1.0 (2021-04-14)](https://pip-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog/#id17)

Comment: How would you compile from a `setup.py`/`.cfg`?  I don't think that's actually supported

Comment: I've edited my answer with links to the documentation.